# How to extract URL using VBA from a section tag?

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am looking for away to extract a specific type of URLs from HTML such as below:
The unique identifier here is the value under data-spec-code such as PROROC & KROROC.

```html
<section data-spec-code="PROROC" only-child="">
    <div class="test-class">
        <div only-child="" class=" col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 show-top-border hidden-xs tech-spec-title-container stack-0">
            <div class="test-class-title">
                <h5 class="top-offset-10 bottom-offset-0 force-bold-font"><span>Data </span></h5>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div only-child="" class=" col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 show-top-border hidden-xs tech-spec-title-container stack-1">
            <div class="test-class-title">
                <!----><em>&nbsp;<span class="hidden">Data </span></em>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div only-child="" class=" col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 show-top-border hidden-xs tech-spec-title-container stack-2">
            <div class="test-class-title">
                <!----><em>&nbsp;<span class="hidden">Data </span></em>
                <!----><small class="help-me-choose-link helpmechoosestyle"><a href="//www.url-i-want-to-extract.com" target="_blank">URL 1</a></small></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section data-spec-code="KROROC" only-child="">
    <div class="test-class">
        <div only-child="" class=" col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 show-top-border hidden-xs tech-spec-title-container stack-0">
            <div class="test-class-title">
                <h5 class="top-offset-10 bottom-offset-0 force-bold-font"><span>Data 2</span></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div only-child="" class=" col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 show-top-border hidden-xs tech-spec-title-container stack-1">
            <div class="test-class-title">
                <!----><em>&nbsp;<span class="hidden">Data 2</span></em>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div only-child="" class=" col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 show-top-border hidden-xs tech-spec-title-container stack-2">
            <div class="test-class-title">
                <!----><em>&nbsp;<span class="hidden">Data 2</span></em>
                <!----><small class="help-me-choose-link helpmechoosestyle"><a href="//www.2nd-url-i-want-to-extract.com" target="_blank">URL 2</a></small></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I have done a code based on research from stackoverflow and google but i could only extract all the links from the page or with getElementsBy.

I wasn't able to use those options since the hyperlink is nested in another tag and the page has too many hyperlinks. I also tried querySelector but failed.

I hope i could get some advice/guidance from you all on how to achieve this.

Below is my expected result:

PROROC www.url-i-want-to-extract.com

KROROC www.2nd-url-i-want-to-extract.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would help to see the actual code in addition to your description of it.

You could start with attribute selectors to target elements with those attribute=value pairs and grab child a tags

```
Dim i As Long
With ie.document.querySelectorAll("[data-spec-code=PROROC] a, [data-spec-code=KROROC] a")
    For i = 0 To .Length - 1
        Debug.Print .Item(i).href
    Next
End With
```